# Replace multiple lines after pattern in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to write a python script to replace first word in multiple lines after my pattern, by now I can only replace 1 line after my pattern, how can it replace more lines? Let's say 3 lines.

lines.txt (input file, pattern"section 2") :

```
section 1
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
endsection
section 2
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
endsection
section 3
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
endsection
```

lines_mod.txt (result with my current code) :

```
section 1
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
endsection
section 2
mod 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
endsection
section 3
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
endsection
```

Here is my python script:

```
with open('E:/lines.txt') as fin, open('E:/lines_m.txt', 'w') as fout:
    flag = 0
    for line in fin:
        if flag == 1:
            mod_line = 'mod ' + line.split()[-1] + '\n'
            fout.write(mod_line)
            flag = 0
            continue
        fout.write(line)
        if line.find('section 2') != -1:
            flag = 1
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: It's because your setting your flag to 0 after you find `'section 2'`, and then write a line to file out. You won't find section 2 ever again. If you want to keep modding all of section 2. don't set `flag = 0` after one write line, but set it after you hit `endsection`

Comment: Update the indentation of your code please.

Comment: @MooingRawr:I don't want replace all lines in 'section 2', I just want to replace some of them.

Comment: @Tian then have a counter for the number of lines

Comment: @MooingRawr:I am very new to programming and python. Could you please show me the counter thing? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list_of_words_to_replace = ['mod','apple','xxx']
with open('E:/lines.txt') as fin, open('E:/lines_mod.txt', 'w') as fout:
    flag = 0
    counter = 0  # <<<<------- added a counter 
    for line in fin:
        if flag == 1:
            counter += 1 #<<<<-------- increasing counter by one every time it loops
            mod_line = list_of_words_to_replace[counter-1] + line.split()[-1] + '\n'  #<---- changed 'mod' to a list of words to replaced.... yes  I know it's counter - 1 because we made counter start at 1 before counting and list index starts at 0 
            fout.write(mod_line)
            if counter > 3: #replaces 3 lines you can replace the number 3 with however many lines you want to override. 
                flag = 0
            continue
        fout.write(line)
        if line.find('section 2') != -1:
            flag = 1
            counter = 0 #<<<<--------- just in case you want to find anotehr section
```

Like in the comments said. You were turning `flag = 0` after one writeline, so we now have a counter that counts how many lines you want to write and when it goes over it sets `flag = 0`.

Any other questions?

Comment: Thanks and sorry, when I see the result with your code, I forget one thing: I want the first word of the lines be replaced by different word, say mod 1, apple 2, xxx 3. I will update my question.

Comment: `mod_line = 'mod ' + line.split()[-1] + '\n'` replace `'mod'` with a variable of what you want it to be. see edited answer

Comment: @MooningRawr:As your last comment in the code, I want repeat another sections, so I will use a "section" list instead of pattern 'section 2' for loop, but there are multiple words to replace per section, and per section has different words, have any idea to loop them?

Comment: Do another list per section and replace the `list_of_words_to_replace` with the correct section list and change it like that.

Comment: I have post a further question for this one [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39727917/specific-lines-replace-with-multiple-search-patterns-in-python). Any chances for help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to revisit your flag update criteria to match the expected output.

Since you set `flag = 1` for the `if line.find('section 2') != -1` condition, it will modify only one line following the matched line.

Since you mention you want to replace more lines, you can probably add a counter that tracks the number of lines you've modified since `flag = 1`... and when you hit the desired number of lines, then reset `flag = 0`.

```
count = 0

for line in fin:
    if flag == 1 and count < 3:
        mod_line = 'mod ' + line.split()[-1] + '\n'
        count += 1
        fout.write(mod_line)
        continue
```