# Modtify specific lines depending on conditions in python

Tags: python

I am writing a python script for lines replacement.
Basically, I want some lines, say under **"ObjectAlias Here" section | bewteen "BeginKeyframe" and "EndKeyframe" | first 6 lines under each "default" that not startswith "-"**

The main part of my files look like:

```
# ...
# BeginObject
# lines
# ObjectAlias XXX
# lines
# BeginKeyframe
#   -1.000 24 default
#   12 lines                # not here since "default" line starts with "-"
#   0.000 24 default
#   12 lines                # first 6 lines need to be modified
#   1.000 24 default
#   12 lines                # first 6 lines need to be modified
#   ...
# EndKeyframe
# lines
# EndObject
# {
# next object YYY section
# }
# ...
```

Here is my code by now, it only success under first "default" without startswith "-", I know it is because I set tag to False, but I have to make sure only first 6 lines to be modified under each "default".
What can I do with the current code?

```
def update(fileobj, objlist):
    fileobj.seek(0)
    tmpscene = ""
    tag = False
    count = 0
    obj = None
    for line in fileobj:
        if tag and count < 6:
            offset = t_objdict[obj].split(",")[count]
            mod = "  " + convert(line, offset) + line.split(None, 1)[-1]
            tmpscene += mod
            count += 1
            if count > 5:
                tag = False     # Here is my problem!
            continue
        tmpscene += line
        if "ObjectAlias" in line:
            for obj in objlist:
                if "ObjectAlias " + obj + "\n" in line:
                    for line in fileobj:
                        tmpscene += line
                        if line.strip().endswith("default") and not line.strip().startswith("-"):
                            tag = True
                            count = 0
                            break
                    break
    return tmpscene
```

**EDIT: ** Rewrite my code, still not works right.

Comment: Assuming the content in your input file looks exactly similar to the file you've given (at least upto 2 DataPattern); your first if clause evaluates to true if the incoming line has "ObjPattern" in the string. However, that is present only in a few lines. So, your first search most of the time evaluates to false

Comment: Further, even when it evaluates to true, you then again try to iterate over the same file object over an over again. What is the purpose of that? if you could add a little bit more explaining, would be able to help. Are you open to maybe changing your code with some different logic to accomplish your objective?

Comment: Also, could you post some of the content from your dictionary?

Comment: Check if the obj exist, if true, replace content in location. Dict looks like: apple:1.2, 0.4, 0.1, 2.7, 0.8, 0.3

Comment: Is a key maps to a list in the dictionary?

Comment: Dictionary comes line by line from a extra config file. Use its keys for obj interate, its value for contents of replacement. I am pretty new to python, dont know "key maps" thing.

Comment: In your case, the key is "apple" and it maps to the value 1.2, 0.4, 0.1, 2.7, 0.8, 0.3, which I assume is a list. Correct?

Comment: Yes! Any idea to correct my code？

Comment: Can you update the answer with what you exactly want to do (may be in pseudo code)? We can then see how to do it. I still can't really understand what your objective is. You don't mention anything about the dictionary in your description. If you could describe to us how you would do this manually, we can do it in Python.

Comment: @picmate I have updated the question and code again. About the dictionary part, it is just a list of float for offering value, and it should works fine.